# 100% width image

Tags: javascript, html, css, width

I have a footer where I have a rounded-left-image, then the middle with repeat, and lastly the rounded-right-image.

How can I achieve perfect responsive scaling without overlapping? 
Something like:
`.paperBottom.middle {float:left; width: (100% -40px)}` (40px being the width of the right-image)

**Setup:**

```
<div class="paperBottomWrapper"> 
   <div class="paperBottom left"> </div>
   <div class="paperBottom middle"> </div>
   <div class="paperBottom right"> </div>
</div>
```

The issue is, that the left and right have rounded graphics and it all have to come nicely together.

Answer (score 3):

you Can use css `display:table` property for this:

```
.paperBottomWrapper{
 width:100%;
 display:table;
}
.paperBottom{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/A34pt/

**OR**

you can achieve this without `display:table` also.

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/A34pt/1/

Answer (score 1):

[here's a sample](http://jsfiddle.net/akF9h/1/)

```
<div class="paperBottomWrapper"> 
   <div class="paperBottom left"> </div>
   <div class="paperBottom right"> </div>
   <div class="paperBottom middle"> </div>
</div>​

/*the containing div*/
.paperBottomWrapper {
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;        
}

/*putting height so we can see it in action*/
.paperBottomWrapper > * {
    height:50px;
}

/*middle repeating area*/
.middle{
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;
    background:green;  
}

/*the edges*/
.left{
    float:left;
    background:red;  
    width:50px;    
}

.right{
    float:right;
    background:red;   
    width:50px;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to be running jQuery UI and are just trying to round the bottom corners of a div, you could simply do it like this:

```
<div class="paperBottomWrapper ui-corner-bottom" style="width:100%"> 
  Stuff  
</div>
```

To get the background effect you're looking for with the jQuery method, just tile your background image in the paperBottomWrapper background.  The rounded corners will adjust appropriately.

There are quite a few other ways you could approach this.  For example, put the full background on the wrapper, then put the corner images into the two outer divs and float them appropriately.

Or, you could try the standard Sliding Door technique as described [here](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/)

There are several other javascript rounded corner apps out there as well.

Answer (score 0):

use attribute float:left in all 3 classes and specify the specific width for left and right div's, then specify the width of middle div by subtracting the sum of width of left and right divs. The sum of the width of 3 divs must be same as your wrapper widht

Comment: I think his grid is fluid and thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### HTML

```
<div class="paperBottomWrapper"> 
   <div class="paperBottom left">Left </div>
   <div class="paperBottom middle">Middle</div>
   <div class="paperBottom right"> Right</div>
</div>​
```

#### CSS

```
paperBottomWrapper { width:100%; }
.paperBottom { float:left; padding:1px }
.left { width :33%;background-color:red; }
.middle{ width :33%;background-color:green; }
.right { width :33%;background-color:blue; }
```

See [`DEMO`](http://jsfiddle.net/2y35N/1)

Comment: You are scaling the images from left and right too. I think what we need here is a method that scales only the middle section.

Answer (score 0):

You can use position: absolute to your corner divs to place on the left and right and the same background color to corner divs as page background has. Of course this only works when you use only colors for main background color.

If background color: #333

```
.paperBottomWrapper{
position: relative;
}

.paperBottom.left{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: #333 url(YOUR_IMAGE);
}

.paperBottom.right{
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
background: #333 url(YOUR_IMAGE);
}

.paperBottom.middle{
width: 100%;
background: url(YOUR_IMAGE);
}
```